# Modify the text of my radio input button?

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, innerhtml

Your average radio button has a name and value, but also some text next to it, in this case "Change this text."

How can I change this in javascript?  Or even alert it? AFAIK, it is NOT the .inner html.

HTML:

```
            <input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="Array 1"> Change this text
```

Javascript

```
    var confirmIExist = document.getElementsByName("radioOption1");
alert(confirmIExist.innerHTML);
    //alerts undefined
```

If it's not .innerHTML, what is it? if I grab the input object with either getElementByName or getElementById, what chunk after that represents the Alert text?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set inner html for a input element. instead wrap your text with a  and give it a ID

```
<input type="radio" name="radioOption1" value="Array 1"> <label id="radioText">Change this text</label>
```

Comment: Why use a `<span>` when we have [`<label>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/label.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `alert(confirmIExist[0].nextSibling.textContent)`, but wouldn't it be better to place the text next to the radio button in a `<label>` and then get the inner html of that

```
<input type="radio" id="radioOption1" name="radioOption1" value="Array 1"><label for="radioOption1" id="r1option">Change this text</label>
...
var label = document.getElementById("r1option");
alert(label.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a self-closing element. It cannot have `innerHTML`

`nextSibling` will return the Node that follows the radio button.

```
document.getElementsByName('radioOption1')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'Text changed';
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4WEDR/)

Answer (score 0):

confirmIExist[0].nextSibling.textContent="abc"