# Adding an HTML element (a button to a form) when an event happens (when another button, from another form, is clicked), using EJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ejs

I am building a Node.js server and using Express.
In an EJS view, I have a form with an event listener, that is, when a given radiobutton is clicked, a function is called:

```
// the way thearray is created is omitted
<% for(var i=0; i<therray.length; i++) { %> 
// parts omitted      
<td>     
<form id= <%= "question_examen"+i %> > // the form that triggers the event
<input type="radio" id= <%= "examen_non"+i %> name="examen" value="non" checked>Non
<input type="radio" id= <%= "examen_oui"+i %> name="examen" value="<%= i %>" onClick= <%= "exam("+i+")" %>>Oui
</form>                     
</td>
<td>     
<form id= <%= "question_selection"+i %> > // the second form, empty at the beginning, but that I want to enrich (see below)
</form>                     
</td>
// parts omitted
<% } %>
```

I want the function exam(i), that is trigerred by the first form, to add new radiobuttons to the second form. This is my function:

```
<script type='application/javascript'>
    function exam(i) {      
        alert(i);  // just to check it is correctly triggered (it is the case)

        // code with mistakes, I guess, since it's not working:                       

        document.createElement("inputnon");
        input.type ="radio";
        input.id= <%= "selection_non"+i %>;
        input.name="selection";
        input.value="non";
        input.innerHTML="Non";
        document.getElementById("#question_selection"+i).appendChild(inputnon);

        document.createElement("inputoui");
        input.type ="radio";
        input.id= <%= "selection_oui"+i %>;
        input.name="selection";
        input.value="oui";
        input.innerHTML="Oui";
        document.getElementById("#question_selection"+i).appendChild(inputoui);

   }
</script>
```

Comment: I have corrected the id of the second form (it was wrong in this question, but not in the code I actually have), thank you @Marcelo-Waisman for noticing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mistakes indeed :)
1) you are trying to access the second form using the wrong id

```
<form id= <%= "selection_examen"+i %> >...
...
document.getElementById("#question_selection"+i).appendChild(inputoui);
```

2) you need to concat the input's id using straight js, no EJS is needed.

To fix it do this:

```
input.id= "selection_non"+i;
```

Instead of:

```
input.id= <%= "selection_non"+i %>;
```

3) you are creating an element without declaring and assigning it to a variable, and the element you were creating wasn't a valid input

To fix it do this:

```
var inputnon = document.createElement("input");
inputnon.type ="radio";
...
```

Instead of this:

```
document.createElement("inputnon");
input.type ="radio";
...
```

1. you do not need innerHTML in a radio button so you can safely remove the following lines:

   `input.innerHTML="Non";
   ...
   input.innerHTML="Oui";`

Try the following code (did not run it though, so it might have more errors):

```
<script>
    function exam(i) {      
        alert(i);  // just to check it is correctly triggered (it is the case)

        // hopefully the following code will run:                       

        var inputnon = document.createElement("input");
        inputnon.type ="radio";
        inputnon.id= "selection_non"+i;
        inputnon.name="selection";
        inputnon.value="non";
        document.getElementById("question_selection"+i).appendChild(inputnon);

        var inputoui = document.createElement("input");
        inputoui.type ="radio";
        inputoui.id= "selection_oui"+i;
        inputoui.name="selection";
        inputoui.value="oui";
        document.getElementById("question_selection"+i).appendChild(inputoui);

   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Point 1 was just a typo I had made in the question (it is now corrected), but point 2 and 3 were real mistakes!

Comment: For the problem that a radio button has not inner HTML, I found information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179769/modify-the-text-of-my-radio-input-button. I try to add the following code to the function but it does not work: `var labelnon = document.createElement("label");      labelnon.for="selection_non"+i; labelnon.innerHTML = "Non";        document.getElementById("selection_non"+i).appendChild(labelnon);`

Comment: it's not the same case, in their case they were referring to a label element which need content to be visible, in your case you are were a radio button which doesn't need content (innerHTML)

Comment: I want some text to be displayed just next to each radio button (so that the user knows what can be selected), I thought it was the aim of the label element...

Comment: I also try this, just to add plain text (string) after the radio button: `var textnon = "Non";           document.getElementById("selection_non"+i).appendChild(textnon);`

Comment: yes, but in your original code you weren't adding a label you were assigning text to the innerHTML of the radio button